# port forwarding in ZTE F620

Tags: port, forwarding

it have been for 3 days to make a port forwarding in my ZTE router and still there is no product. I want to open 80 port for one of my computer (which local adress is 192.168.1.11). ill give you several pictures to show how I am trying to do that and I hope you can guess what is wrong with what:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Obvious question - but have you clicked `add`?

Comment: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/ZTE/F620/HTTP.htm shows slightly different screenshots? Click the Application link near the top of the page.

The menu on the left should change. In this new menu, click Port Forwarding.

You should now see a new menu. In this new menu, click Advanced.

Comment: Have you got latest firmware?

Comment: :D yes of course I clicked add :D

Comment: http://snag.gy/7F52D.jpg here, my menu is different. I don't know, ZTE have poor site and I even couldn't find latest firmware version for my router.